# imported SVG text make editable , is there any way to do with fabricjs?

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am working on Project that using fabricjs, I have imported SVG into canvas, But I want to edit text using iText , is it possible ?

or is there any way to convert Text object to IText Object ?

Comment: iText like the [java pdf library](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf)? So the changes would be made server-side, before-hand and unrelated to fabric wouldn'it?

Comment: IText is fabricjs, Object which allow to interact with Text...

Comment: Hi @Vishal Dobariya can you do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert Text Object to IText object by programming on Canvas `object:added` event. You just need to take care copy only required Text object properties. But Don't change IText object's type property value.

Comment: Can I use `jQuery.extends()` method to copy properties ?

Comment: No, You shouldn't because it will copy Text Object type property's value into IText type property value, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Do you really need to hand copy these properties over to create an IText from Text?

Comment: Do you have any  suggestion ? or better idea ?